# Error when use forever in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm a newbie in sails. I found some error when I run sails app by 
using '**forever start app.js --prod**'

my style was broken and there is one error in console,

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.191/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=hFy1TK_-48EQBVIyAAAE' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

But when I run sails by '**sails lift**', it normally work.
And if I disable grunt by put

```
{
   "hooks": {
       "grunt": false
   }
}
```

in ***.sailsrc*** file, it normally work too.

I don't know how to run sails by forever without disable grunt.
I really need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as your sailsrc, it would not build / compressed static file in production mode.

please try steps,

`grunt build prod
forever start app.js --prod`