# Sails.js - How to use forever and not start grunt automatically on server start?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm running into an issue using Sails.js framework (node.js).

It seems like it runs automatically `grunt` when the server starts. But I don't want that. In order to prevent this, it is possible to configure in a `.sailsrc` file that we don't want grunt to start. (http://www.sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets/disabling-grunt)

But this specific configuration file is only taken into account when we run the server using `sails lift` command. It won't be used if we use `node app.js`.

Point is, I want to use forever with sails. But I don't know how to run forever and take into account the `.sailsrc` file so that Sails doesn't start grunt on its own.

I'm using BrowserSync and I need to startup things in a really specific order, it works fine when using `sails lift` and `grunt` separately, but I don't get any hot refresh that way.

*I found a similar issue here, but it doesn't help me much.* [Error when use forever in sails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935115/error-when-use-forever-in-sails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you get the "Your `.sailsrc` file(s) will be ignored." error.

Running npm install rc --save in both the project root directory and node_modules/sails, and adding

```
"hooks": {
    "grunt": false
 }
```

to .sailsrc solved this issue for me.

**Update**: if you're using an older version of Sails, such as sails@0.10.5 you have to change the line "rc": "^0.5.5” to "rc": "^0.5.0" in node_modules/sails/package.json, remove rc and reinstall it with the older version of rc (which is used in the newer versions of Sails).

Comment: @Vadorequest: I was able to replicate the error in sails@0.10.5 too. It seems to be an issue with rc@0.5.5

Comment: Better to use `"rc": "0.5.5"` then, so it doesn't automatically install newest minor version. I made the change but it's still not using the `.sailsrc` file. I don't get any error message like `"Your .sailsrc file(s) will be ignored."` but it does act differently using sails lift or node app.js

Comment: Ahhhh, that's because I've got a custom `app.js` based on a really old version of sails.

Comment: I replaced my custom app.js file which deals with this kind of stuff and it takes into account the `.sailsrc` file whether I'm using sails lift or ndoe app.js. Thanks ;)

Comment: Btw, once I replaced my app.js with the file generated by sails in `~0.11.1-rc1` I removed the `rc` package from the project and it worked fine, I still have the rc package within the sails package in version 0.5.5. (This project is still under sails 0.10.5, but my -g sails package is under `~0.11.1-rc1`, that's why I used the app.js from a newer version but it seems to work fine.

Comment: Good to know. I'm running sails@0.11.0. It could be an error with rc 0.5.5 that only occurs in older versions of sails.

Answer (score 1):

In the sails book from Manning:

> Note: Grunt is also optional. If for some reason you enjoy doing manual repetitive tasks simply delete the Gruntfile.js from the root of your project. No more Grunt. When you restart Sails via sails lift warnings that the “Gruntfile could not be found” and that “no grunt tasks will be run” are displayed.

Give that a shot

Comment: No, I use grunt. I just don't want it to be started by sails, I want have control over it. Anyway, @piscator solution worked for me, but yours is definitely a solution if you don't use grunt at all.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `hooks.grunt = false` keeps being valid for Sails v1.x